# Find contour of 2D object in image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, contour

I have this problem: I have this 2D binary image and I want to extract the contour of the object in this image.
This is the image: 
[image]

I want to have the same matrix image but with ones only in the contour of the object and zeros elsewhere.
Is there a solution?
If so, is there any implementation to do the same thing also for a 3D object?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox you can use [`bwperim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwperim.html)

```
BW = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/05T06.png');
BW = BW(:,:,1) == 255;

boundary = bwperim(BW);

imshow(boundary)
```

[image]

Ultimately what this does, is performs a convolution on the original image to erode it and then computes the difference between the eroded version and the original version. So if you don't have the toolbox you can do this with `conv2` (or `convn` in 3D).

```
eroded = ~conv2(double(~BW), ones(3), 'same');
boundary = BW - eroded;
```

Or in 3D:

```
eroded = ~convn(double(~BW_3D), ones(3,3,3), 'same');
boundary = BW_3D - eroded;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly with bwperim function!